# Location don't works on server

Tags: javascript, google-maps, location

I'm having a trouble with the Google Location service, the thing is that what I'm doing looks good and works fine on localhost, but when I move all to the server to access them from my domain, all still working except for the Location tracker...

this is the code: (only the important part)

```
            <div style="margin-top:50px; max-width:650px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
            <p id='frasePermitir' style='font-size: 140%; text-align: center;'>Permita el acceso a su ubicaci&oacute;n para registrar el caso</p>
            <p id='fraseNombreCiudad' style='font-size: 120%;'></p>
            <input type='hidden' name='usrLat' id='usrLat' value='' />
            <input type='hidden' name='usrLon' id='usrLon' value='' />
            <input type='hidden' name='usrCity' id='usrCity' value='' />
            <!--<div id="map" style='align-content:center;'></div>-->
            <input type='button' class="fileUpload btn btn-warning" value='Permitir' id='btnPermitir' onclick='crgUbicacion();' />
            <div id='divCargando' style='display:none;'>
                <div class="loader" id="loader" style='width:30px; height:30px;'></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="margin-top:50px; max-width:650px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center;">
            <button type="submit" id="btnEnviar" class="btn btn-info" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return checkDat();"><b>Enviar datos</b></button>
        </div>

    </form> <!--aqui termina el formulario de datos-->

    <script>
        function crgUbicacion() { //se cambio el nombre de la funcion initMap() -> crgUbicacion(), porque sino no lo toma el onclick del btn
            var divCrg = document.getElementById("divCargando");
            divCrg.style = "width:50px; height:50px; float:left;";

            /*var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
              zoom: 6
            });
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});*/

            // Try HTML5 geolocation.
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var pos = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };

                    /*se llenan los input hidden que contienen la latitud y logitud*/
                    var usrLat = document.getElementById("usrLat");
                    var usrLon = document.getElementById("usrLon");
                    usrLat.value = position.coords.latitude;
                    usrLon.value = position.coords.longitude;

                    /*con esto se obtiene el nombre de la localidad*/
                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
                    geocoder.geocode({
                        'location': pos
                        // ej. "-34.653015, -58.674850"
                        }, function(results, status) {
                            // si la solicitud fue exitosa
                            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                // si encontró algún resultado.
                                if (results[1]) {
                                    var usrCity = document.getElementById("usrCity");
                                    usrCity.value = results[1].formatted_address;
                                    document.getElementById("fraseNombreCiudad").innerHTML = "Tu ubicaci&oacute;n es <span style='color:#298A08'>"+results[1].formatted_address+".</span>";
                                    document.getElementById("frasePermitir").innerHTML = "Listo, ya tenemos tu ubicaci&oacute;n";
                                    document.getElementById("btnPermitir").style = 'display:none;';
                                    //se oculta el icono de carga
                                    divCrg.style = "display:none;";
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    /*---------------------------------------------*/

                    /*infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                    infoWindow.setContent('Encontramos tu ubicaci&oacute;n!');
                    map.setCenter(pos);*/
                }, function() {
                    handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                });
            } else {
              // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
              handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            }
        }

        function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                                  'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                                  'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=---MYKEYYYY---&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Pd. I erase the api-key from the last link to post here, that isn't the error.

Thank u all! Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes from your code there isn't a problem but the problem might only be with your domain ssl certificate, browsers now require your website to have an SSL Certificate for you to fetch user's location data. check in your browser console, i'm sure you will find this error, but if you try running your script on Edge Browser i'm sure it will be working

Comment: Cool! thats sound logic, I will try with a ssl certificate!